# Tipo criado está retornando "Null"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

Estou criando uma API que trabalha com uma lista de contatos e Agendas, estou utilizando o Entity para a todas as interações com o DB.

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, as classes Contact e ContactBook estão usando o relacionamento 1N(um para muitos)

```
namespace TesteBackendEnContact.Core.Entities
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ContactBook ContactBook { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
}
```

A classe ContactBook

```
namespace TesteBackendEnContact.Core.Entities
{
    public class ContactBook
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A migration efetuada ficou da seguinte maneira

```
public partial class UpdateDB : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ContactBook",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "AsString(50)", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ContactBook", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Contact",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                ContactBookId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "AsString(50)", nullable: false),
                Phone = table.Column<string>(type: "AsString(20)", nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "AsString(50)", nullable: true),
                Address = table.Column<string>(type: "AsString(100)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Contact", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Contact_ContactBook_ContactBookId",
                    column: x => x.ContactBookId,
                    principalTable: "ContactBook",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Contact_ContactBookId",
            table: "Contact",
            column: "ContactBookId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Contact");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "ContactBook");
    }
}
```

porem estou enfrentando um problema na hora de retornar o item Contact, quando efetuo o teste pelo Swagger do Requeste de cadastro, tudo funciona perfeito.

quando faço o request Get pra me retornar o item, deveria vir assim

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "contactBook": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Mercado"
    },
    "name": "Marcelo",
    "phone": "11 935246394",
    "email": "Marcelo@gmail.com",
    "address": "Rua dos testes"
  }
]
```

mas está vindo assim

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "contactBook": null,
    "name": "Marcelo",
    "phone": "11 935246394",
    "email": "Marcelo@gmail.com",
    "address": "Rua dos testes"
  }
]
```

o item ContactBook vem como Null

***Edit:***

Dentro da Controller, a chamada está assim

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Contact> Get()
{
    return repoContact.GetAll();
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Contact Get(int id)
{
    return repoContact.Get(id);
}
```

mas o método Get dentro da classe mãe que vai ser herdada está assim

```
public List<T> GetAll()
{
    return _dataBaseContext.Set<T>().ToList();
}

public T Get(params object[] varT)
{
    return _dataBaseContext.Set<T>().Find(varT);
}
```

Comment: Adicione o código de como você está chamando o `GET`, para vermos se o problema pode estar na sua chamada.

Comment: Adicionado @LeandroPaixão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que basta tu declarar que quer usar o LazyLoad no seu contexto.

Primeiro no `Startup.cs`, na classe `ConfigureService()` declare na conexão com o banco que você quer usar o LazyLoad

`services.AddDbContext<SeuDbContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlite(SuaConnectionString));`

Depois tu tem que declarar a propiedade dentro da classe como `virtual` para poder ser sobreposta (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactBook ContactBook { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```